# plotting a graph with 3 curves time series data

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a pretty basic questions, but I wasn't able to find an answer.
I would like to create a graph with three curves (time series data) without using ts.plot. 
Here are the three data sets:

```
a1 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),"years")
a2 <- rnorm(21,10,1)
Dollar <- data.frame(a1,a2)
dates <- as.Date(Dollar[,1], "%d.%m.%Y",tz="GMT") 
xtsplot1 <- as.xts(Dollar[,2], dates)


b1 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),"years")
b2 <- rnorm(21,10,1)
EURO <- data.frame(b1,b2)
xtsplot2 <- as.xts(EURO[,2], dates)

c1 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),"years")
c2 <- rnorm(21,10,1)
YEN <- data.frame(c1,c2)
xtsplot3 <- as.xts(Dollar[,2], dates)
```

I now want to plot the three curves. I wrote this code:

```
plot(xtsplot1, xtsplot2, xtsplot3, xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = FALSE)
```

But it doesn't work.

any suggestions? :)

Comment: One can also plot one time series and then add two others with `lines` function. Downside of that is that y bounding box is determined by first time series. Frank DiTraglia's proposed `matplot` handles this problem and is closest syntactically to what you want. For arbitrary number of time series on single plot refer to `ggplot2` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use matplot as follows:

```
matplot(cbind(xtsplot1, xtsplot2, xtsplot3), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = FALSE, type = 'l')
```

Comment: Also, there's a typo in your code: when creating the third xts object, I think you meant to put "YEN" where you put "Dollar"

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thanks! But if I now want to add a x-axis it with the commant: `d1y <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),length.out=24)`

`axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(d1y),labels=format(d1y,"%Y"))`
`title(ylab = "Value")`
`title(xlab = "Time")` it does not work...